# "TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list" when appending a file

Tags: python

I am currently working on a small program in order to create random serial numbers. If the serial already exists, it will scrap the idea. If not, it checks to see if the serial was once existent and is now void. If not this either, it will append to a file. I want this program to be able to run an infinite amount of times without causing problems, which, up until the last point, does not.

My code is as follows:

```
def GenerateSerial():
    '''This will generate a new serial number based on pre-existing'''
    HexidecimalKey = open('Hexidecimal_No_Spaces.txt', 'r')
    Serials = open('ConcurrentSerials.txt', 'r')
    Void = open('VoidSerials.txt', 'r')
    GenerationKey = HexidecimalKey.read()
    currentSerials = Serials.read()
    voidSerials = Void.read()
    ###print(GenerationKey)
    SizeOfSerial = random.randint(3,6)
    NewSerial = random.sample(GenerationKey, SizeOfSerial)
    print(NewSerial)
    NewSerial1 = ' '.join(str(x) for x in NewSerial)
    print(NewSerial1)
    for serial in currentSerials:
        if NewSerial in currentSerials:
            print("That serial is already in the current serials")
            print("Scrapping serial and restarting generation")
    for serials in voidSerials:
        if NewSerial in voidSerials:
            print("That serial has already been previously used and voided")
            print("It cannot be used again")
    else:
        Serials.close()
        ###Serials = open('ConcurrentSerials.txt', 'w')
        with open("ConcurrentSerials.txt", "a") as myfile:
            myfile.write(NewSerial1 + "\n")
        ###serialsAppend = Serials.read()
        ###Serials.write(NewSerial)
```

When I run the code once, it appends the 'ConcurrentSerials.txt' file with the generated serial. However, when I run it the second time, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joe\Documents\Serial Number Testing\Testing.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Joe\Documents\Serial Number Testing\Testing.py", line 50, in main
    GenerateSerial()
  File "C:\Users\Joe\Documents\Serial Number Testing\Testing.py", line 30, in GenerateSerial
    if NewSerial in currentSerials:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

Can someone help me with understanding why this happens? I've tried searching around and rectifying the process, but it does not work to any extent.

Thank you for any help,

Joseph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says you're trying to see whether a list is in a string.

`NewSerial` [is of type **`list`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample).

`currentSerials` [is of type **`str`**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

Instead of:

```
for serial in currentSerials:
    if NewSerial in currentSerials:
        ...
```

You probably need:

```
for serial in NewSerial:
    if serial in currentSerials:
         ...
```

This will check against the entire contents of the file. If that isn't large, it's not a problem. But if you want to be efficient, it's probably best to read all the current serials into a set and perform a set intersection.

Comment: So where would I be adding/changing this within my code? I'm not the most acquainted person so I need to slight help.

Comment: The program runs every time, which is grand. However, every time I run it, I get the message of "That serial is already in the current serials" message. I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: What is the value of `NewSerial`?

Comment: The value of `NewSerial` changes each time as it's randomly generated. Here's an output of two runs of the program:

**Run 1:**
`Please make your choice: 1
['k', 'j', 'c', 't', '7', 'e']
k j c t 7 e
That serial is already in the current serials
Scrapping serial and restarting generation`


**Run 2:**
`Please make your choice: 1
['e', '3', 'c']
e 3 c
That serial is already in the current serials
Scrapping serial and restarting generation`


I have had to redact the amount of print statements I get with `"That serial..."` as it seems to print it for each character in the list.

Comment: I have realised my problem.
It was a self created issue in this part of the code:
`NewSerial1 = ' '.join(str(x) for x in NewSerial)
    print(NewSerial1)
    for serial in currentSerials:
        if NewSerial1 in currentSerials:`
Where I had before put `if NewSerial in currentSerials`, whereas I should have typed `if NewSerial1 in currentSerials`, as it was trying to compare the lists to the one string that got saved in the file.
_Thank you for your help, however_, as, without it, I wouldn't have come to realise what my problem was anyway!
Many thanks,
Joseph.